# list of available functions for jQuery(window)

Tags: javascript, jquery

where can i find a list of available standard functions for `jQuery(window).` I know about load and focus.

Comment: `conosle.log(jQuery(window));`

Comment: Have a look at this:
[Link](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/#methods_block)

Comment: You can just type it into the console in firebug.

Comment: @Alex J, not necessary. Works in Chrome developper tools as well. Can't say for IE as I am not using this s..t.

Comment: @Joseph, I haven't used the console much in FF. I just downloaded firebug and input this conosle.log(jQuery(window)); on the right box and hit run. it gives me a reference error on both FF & Chrome. Says console is not defined.

Comment: sorry, if I could spell console correctly, it would work :). Could you post this as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open your console, type:

```
console.log(jQuery(window));
```

Hit Enter (Ctrl-Enter in Firebug), and you'll see it all there!